# Generate function from discrete data (time-series)

Tags: transformation, estimation, time-series

How to transform discrete data into continous function ? I am working extensively with time series data and I would like to reduce amount of data in our frontend application. It would be cool to generate function which would match to our discrete data series.

Input data :

```
time       value (between 0 and 10000, 2 scale precision)
00:00:01   5121.57
00:00:02   3200.0
00:00:03   4421.56
00:00:04   7833.10
etc...
```

Output :

```
 value = function_generated_from_timeseries(time)
```

(I don't need really *precise* representation)

What mathematical approach and methods should I study ?

Comment: Are you looking for a polynomial regression ? Post some more data and I shall look at them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put data into Matlab, scatterplot your data, and interpolate with a cubic spline.

Otherwise, depending on the shape, you could use polynomial\trigonometric interpolation. Consider also the opportunity to connect pionts by plotting segments between them, if the grid is not coarse.

I reckon to read something about linear interpolation.